# How to decode old video binary file

Tags: video, codec

I have bunch of old video binary files which are with .VID extenstion. I tried to play it with major players, but it didn't worked out.

Is there any way on linux or in windows to detect which video format is used ?

Those files are from one old cd , which has a program which was playing that videos , but it is now damaged, and I need those videos ...

Any help in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with ffmpeg / mplayer ?

Try with:

> ffmpeg -i yourfile.vid

Comment: ffmpeg -i n10.VID 
ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
n10.VID: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Hmmm if ffmpeg can't understand it, I think it's really difficult to guess what is it.